# Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction when trying to estimate gas

Tags: web3js, gas-estimate

I am trying to run `estimateGas` function on mainnet like the following to send erc721 cryptokitties from one account to another:

```
data.from = <my address>
data.to = <destination address>
data.token = 0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d (cryptokitties contract address)
data.tokenId = 1148166

var getDataForERC721 = function(from, to, contractAddress, tokenId){
    var abi = <myerc721abi>;
    var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
    var data = contract.safeTransferFrom.getData(from, to, tokenId);
    return data;
}

var txdata = getDataForERC721(data.from, data.to, data.token, data.tokenId;

getEstimateGas = async function(from, to, data, value){
    var self = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        web3.eth.estimateGas({
            'from': from,
            'to': to,
            'data': data,
            'value': value
        }, function(err, tx){
            console.log("errror is -> " + err);
            if( err ) resolve(null);
            else resolve(tx);
        });
    });

getEstimateGas(data.from, data.to , txdata, 0x00);
```

I get this error `Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction`. This function works well on Ropsten network, but gives the above error on mainnet.

I am using web3 version `^0.20.6`

## EDIT

I have made sure that `contract.ownerOf(tokenId)` returns the correct address. 
I have also tried replacing `contract.safeTransferFrom.getData(from, to, tokenId)` with `contract.transferFrom.getData(from, to, tokenId)`.
However, I still get the same error.

`console.log(contract.transferFrom.getData(from, to, tokenId))` prints the following:

```
0x23b872dd00000000000000000000000057e7674b1c58a0edce5a62af228ab34f09c00fca000000000000000000000000ae08cf4e3678843bbeb39d0608029b1daa4d51210000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000118506
```

The data that I am now passing to `getEstimateGas` is as follows:

```
{ from: '0x57E7674B1c58A0edce5a62AF228ab34f09C00Fca',
  to: '0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d',
  data:    '0x23b872dd00000000000000000000000057e7674b1c58a0edce5a62af228ab34f09c00fca000000000000000000000000ae08cf4e3678843bbeb39d0608029b1daa4d51210000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000118506',
  value: '0x00' }
```

Here `from` is the address which contains the token, `to` is the contract address (cryptokitties)
and `data` is the data returned from `contract.transferFrom.getData` function.

Here the `from` address is also the owner of the token. So, I guess I don't need to use the `approve` function.

I gained this token with this transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5119c2d5eae0fdc4a0e000b84231cfb5db075efd30fcca3fabe91d2bbfdc9006

Answer (score 1):

`web3.eth.estimateGas` will return that error when there is not enough gas, or when the transaction fails, and for the looks of it, sounds like your transaction might be failing, here is why:

The transaction `safeTransferFrom` is not implemented for cryptokitties, looking at their code, they've implemented interface signatures (ERC-165), there you can check if you can call a function from your code:

```
bytes4 constant InterfaceSignature_ERC721 =
    bytes4(keccak256('name()')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('symbol()')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('totalSupply()')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('balanceOf(address)')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('ownerOf(uint256)')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('approve(address,uint256)')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('transfer(address,uint256)')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('transferFrom(address,address,uint256)')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('tokensOfOwner(address)')) ^
    bytes4(keccak256('tokenMetadata(uint256,string)'));
```

Other ways to check this, is checking their ABI, or looking at their code.

Point is that `safeTransferFrom` is not implemented, and that's why estimateGas fails, likely it worked on Ropsten because the token you are using does implement it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I changed to `transferFrom` function, but still get the same error. I tried to look for their abi. Where can I get it?

Comment: Well, that's another problem, can you provide more information about it? 
Here is their ABI https://etherscan.io/address/0x06012c8cf97bead5deae237070f9587f8e7a266d#code

Comment: I tried using their ABI, but I still get the same error. Do you need to know any specific information? I can confirm that `contract.ownerOf(tokenId)` returns the correct address.

Comment: Again it's a different reason, won't be able to help unless you provide actual code and the steps you followed, otherwise I'm blind, its a different question, if I had to guess, I'd say you might have forgotten to call approve before calling transferFrom, or maybe, the asset was moved and it's throwing

Comment: I added more information to the original post. I did not use the `approve` function since the from address is also the owner of the token. Could you check?

Comment: Use `transfer()` and it will work, `transferFrom()` is used when you are not the owner, their code checks if the owner of the token has called approve on the sender `require(_approvedFor(msg.sender, _tokenId));` since you didn't explicitly called approve on yourself, the transaction fails. This behaviour may seem counter intuitive, but it's the simplest way to implement it and, at this point in time, simpler means better in smart contracts